# Installing LAPACK using CMake on Windows

Tags: cmake, lapack, cmake-gui

I would like to install LAPACK on my Windows.I am using CMake 3.21.0 GUI for my installation and the LAPACK version is 3.9.1.

I encountered the following error message:

```
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeCache.txt.tmp50918
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:181 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:193 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdFortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdFortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdFortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdFortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdFortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdFortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdFortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdFortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:1090 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:81 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:1090 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:81 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:1090 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:81 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:1090 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:81 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:189 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:200 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CMakeFortranCompiler.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:303 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CMakeFortranCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory: C:/Program
  Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CompilerIdC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:1090 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:81 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:1090 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:81 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:122 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:230 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CMakeRCCompiler.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineRCCompiler.cmake:55 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU.cmake:134 (enable_language)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU-Fortran.cmake:2 (__windows_compiler_gnu)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeFortranInformation.cmake:25 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/3.21.0-rc2/CMakeRCCompiler.cmake
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:49 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".F" for file

    C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeFortranCompilerABI.F

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:

    C Fortran RC

  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:20 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - failed
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:188 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:20 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gfortran.exe
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:34 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testFortranCompiler.f
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:39 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".f" for file

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testFortranCompiler.f

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:

    C Fortran RC

  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gfortran.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:47 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

    C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
  The Fortran compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gfortran.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeCache.txt.tmp0c1bd
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
```

I followed the installation guide from here: https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/ (the instruction starts from `Easy Windows Build` part and I am using the `Build Instructions to create LAPACK and LAPACKE 3.5.0 dlls for Windows with MinGW` part. Looking for some insights on what is happening.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to the filename `C:/Program Files/lapack/CMakeCache.txt.tmp50918`, you are trying to use `C:\Program Files\lapack` directory as a build one. Do not do that: the directory `C:\Program Files` is expected to contain only **installed programs**. Choose another build directory. E.g. `C:\lapack-build`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it works! Thank you so much. Sorry for a very noob question hahah. I am not used to windows system.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am currently stuck on step 8. I encountered error during Linking fortran shared library. My issue is the same as this https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/issues/305 but it does not work. If you happen to know a solution toward this. Thanks!

Comment: They suggest adding the compiler option. Did you add that to CMake? You have to be careful that there wasn't a compiler option that resets the build flags after you set the option. In a lot of old codebases, you find people that set the build flags to empty, and then start adding options.